# Problem with Python Tkinter Button command

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a login/sign up system in python using Tkinter. The code is something like:

```
class Sign_Up:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.geometry('500x500')
        self.name = StringVar()
        ...

        label_0 = Label(root, ...)
        entry_0 = entry(root, text = name)
        ...

        self.b = Button(root, command = flag, ...)
        self.mainloop()

    def flag(self):

        name1 = self.name.get()
        ...
```

Flag function checks whether the username is available or passwords match and shows relative messages from tkinter.mesagebox.

Everything works fine and desired when I call the function below:

```
def signup():
    root = Tk()
    s = Sign_Up(root)

signup()
```

However, when I write another class Menu which is a class for a window that has 2 buttons: Sign up and Sign in and pass this function to its button command, it does not work:

```
class Menu:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        ...

        self b1 = (root, command = signup, ...)
        root.mainloop()

    def signup(self):
        root = Tk()
        s = Sign_Up(root)
```

Sign up function does not work with *command* and I assume that the problem is about *get* function in the *flag* function above because every time it shows a warning 'fill in the blanks' which is supposed to be displayed when the length of the entries is 0.

As I said, flag function and sign up class works properly independently, but it does not work when I pass it to tkinter button command. How can I fix this?

Comment: Read [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, Tk() only has to be used for the first window, for the next ones, Toplevel() should be used.